# SKTextureAtlas - Pass in a path to an atlas instead of looking for that specific atlas

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm working on a class to handle character animations. The animations will have different skin tones that the user chooses from in character creation. The atlases for each of the skin tones have the same name but are stored in differently named folders like this:

[image: image 1]

[image: Image 2]

*this is in the xcassets folder*

This should allow my code to be more modular so I don't have to hard-code a ton of stuff. I want my code to locate the chosen skin tone folder and its subdirectories so that the correct animation plays when the animation functions are called.

Current code so far:

```
class Character : SKNode {
    let character: SKSpriteNode
    let base: String
    var textureArray = [SKTexture]()

    init(Base: String) {
        character = SKSpriteNode(texture: nil, size: CGSize(width: 30, height: 44))
        base = Base
        super.init()

        self.addChild(character)
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func northAnimation() {
        let textureAtlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "\(base)")
        var frames:[SKTexture] = []

        for index in 1 ... 6 {
            let textureName = textureAtlas.textureNamed("back_\(index)")
            let texture = textureName
            textureArray = frames

            character.removeAllActions()
            character.run(SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.animate(with: textureArray, timePerFrame: 0.2)))
        }
    }
}
```

In the `init` for the class, the objective is to plug in the name of the folder (which would be set based off of character creation) and then access the corresponding atlases. I'm having trouble figuring out how to find the correct paths to the atlas locations.

How do I pass in a path to an atlas instead of looking for that specific atlas?

Answer (score 1):

All assests in .XCAssets are managed in NSSet mode for a speed reason. In other words, there is no path concept in the file and every name is suppose to be unique.

So you only need to assign a unique name to the atlas like :

"male_pale_back"
"male_pale_backLeft"
"male_pale_backRight"

"male_tan_back"
"male_tan_backLeft"
"male_tan_backRight"

If any file name is not unique, the result is not defined. Probably you cannot get the atlas.

So here `let textureAtlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "\(base)")` if the base name is just `back`. There are more than one back and the loading of atlas failed.

Change the filenames in atlas first. 
Then constitute a new filename : `SKTextureAtlas(named: "male_\(name)_\(base)")` will solve your problem.

Hope you got it.

If you prefer to use filePath, can use second method and not to use .XCASSets.

Refer to `SKTextureAtlas.init(dictionary properties: [String : Any])`

Answer (score 0):

After doing more research into the file structure of Swift, and studying some other games with similar animations, I quickly discovered that what I wanted wasn't possible. I came up with another method that is similar, but not identical to what I wanted in my question.

Here is the altered code. This code is extremely modular and it should work for all the animations I need it to play.

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit

class Character : SKNode {
    let character: SKSpriteNode
    let gender: String
    let tone: String
    var textureArray = [SKTexture]()

    init(Tone: String, Gender: String) {
        character = SKSpriteNode(texture: nil, size: CGSize(width: 45, height: 66))
        gender = Gender
        tone = Tone

        super.init()

        self.addChild(character)
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func moveAnimation(direction: String) {
        let textureAtlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "\(gender)_\(tone)_\(direction)")
        var frames:[SKTexture] = []

        for index in 1 ... 6 {
            let textureName = textureAtlas.textureNamed("\(gender)_\(tone)_\(direction)_\(index)")
            let texture = textureName
            frames.append(texture)
            textureArray = frames

            character.removeAllActions()
            character.run(SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.animate(with: textureArray, timePerFrame: 0.1)))
        }
    }
}
```

I came up with a folder naming format (It happens to pretty much match @E. Coms answer, but there are a couple differences and I came up with it ~8 hours before him.) that allows me to plug any direction, gender, and skin tone with a single function. The format goes `\(gender)_\(tone)_\(direction)` so my atlas folders are named:

[image: Image 1]

Each of the skin tones will be named `male_tan, male_dark` instead of `male_pale` so the atlases won't get confused with each other.

When I initialize a new character, I choose a skin tone and a gender. When I call the animation function, I choose a direction (`back, backLeft, forward, etc.`)

This is pretty much what I needed.

Comment: you should not have the same file name across multiple atlases, you run into the issue of the system possibly pulling the wrong asset when multiple assets are loaded into a cached system

Comment: Each atlas has its own unique name. Not one atlas will overlap with each other. I added an image to my answer to better show what I meant.

Comment: Yes it does, behind the scenes it will

Comment: Now the answer has the image. I don't think you fully understand what I mean.

Comment: It is never a good idea to have 2 files if the same name in xcassets because the ios will search for it somewhere else when it cant find it, so instead of crashing on a bad read, it is going to look in another folder

Comment: First of all, none of the atlases are stored in any folders. They are at the top level in XCassets. Secondly, each of them have *similar* but unique names. Re-read my answer. I need a uniform naming system that has a basic format so I don't have to hard-code a ton of stuff. That was one mistake I made with my first game. Trust me, this is good game design.

Comment: The textures inside your atlases all have the same name

Comment: They don't. The atlas textures each have the same name as the folder but with `_1, _2` etc. at the end of the texture name. That part of my code is older stuff. Let  me change it to my current code.