# Filename for an image in Assets.xcassets

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, xcasset

How do I get the filename for an image stored in Assets.xcassets? I've an image named "default" in an "Avatars" folder in my xcassets. How do I get the filename for this image if possible?

I need the filename to send to a server.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the actual filename is not saved on the compiled assets file, so you can't retrieve it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53187032/sktextureatlas-pass-in-a-path-to-an-atlas-instead-of-looking-for-that-specific/53194056#53194056

Answer (score 2):

Files from `Assets.xcassets` are compiled into a `.car` file by Xcode and have no individual filenames inside your app bundle.

See e.g. [Analysing Assets.car file in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22630418/analysing-assets-car-file-in-ios) for details of how such a `.car` file looks like.